# react-native run-android gives an exception about the PATH connection

Tags: react-native

I am trying to run the react-native run-android command in window 10. I set up the path to the SDK folder using ANDROID_HOME in System Variables of Environment Variables

```
ANDROID_HOME |  C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

And I also set up sdk.dir in the local.properties file

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\owner\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
```

However, when I run the command lines

```
react-native run-android
```

in my project folder C:\Users\owner\Documents\React_Native\MyApplication> It gave me an exception as follow.

```
C:\Users\owner\Documents\React_Native\MyApplication>react-native run-android
Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\Users\owner\Documents\React_Native\MyApplication\node_modules (34ms)
JS server already running.

Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.305 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

Comment: Check if your SDK is installed or your SDK path correctly, and restart you computer to make environment variable effective.

Comment: Probably the sdk is not installed or you missed with adding path specifically.
Hope this will help you configure the sdk as per step 5 and 6. [To Setup SDK PATH windows10](https://medium.com/@prasadjivane/react-native-environment-setup-on-windows-10-47a3b5e833b9)